# Aligning strings with .format()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting, alignment

I have some strings that I'm printing out and I want to align them in order to make them appear neat.

```
colours = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
quantities = {"Red" : 6, "Green" : 4,  "Yellow" : 9
```

Here is how I am currently printing them out:

```
for colour in colours:
  print("{}: {}".format(colours[colour], quantities[colour]))
```

However they come out looking like this:

```
Red: 6
Green: 4
Yellow: 9
```

When I would like them to come out like:

```
Red:      6
Green:    4
Yellow:   9
```

Answer (score 1):

(Correcting some error in you code)... You can use \t to insert tab

```
for colour in colours:
  print("{}:\t {}".format(colour, quantities[colour]))
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work in my code, I have looked into using ljust() but I'm not sure if that would work...

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you try to use \t tabs?